# Custom GridView lagging using multiple Bitmaps

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview, bitmapfactory

I am populating [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) with multiple item,each containing ImageView and TextView, there will be about 100+ such items.
Problem is everything is executing properly but activity is lagging heavily while scrolling,
I tried to [load bitmap efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) by limiting imagesize but with no improvement.

And also note my source of images is Local Filesystem and Category.getCategoryUrl() contains filepath.

Here is my [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) implementation:

```
public class RootCategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Category> {

    private int resource;
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Category> categoryList;
    private DisplayMetrics metrics;

    public RootCategoryAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<Category> categoryList, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
        super(context, resource, categoryList);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.categoryList = categoryList;
        this.metrics = metrics;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CategoryHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            // LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)
            // context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, parent, false);

            holder = new CategoryHolder();
            holder.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.root_category_text);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.root_category_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (CategoryHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Category category = categoryList.get(position);

        holder.title.setText(category.getCategoryName());

        // I think problem starts here but not certain
        holder.options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        holder.options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        holder.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(category.getCategoryUrl(),
                holder.options);
        holder.options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        holder.options.inSampleSize = BasicChores.calculateInSampleSize(
                holder.options, 200, 200);
        holder.bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(category.getCategoryUrl(),
                holder.options);

        holder.image.setImageBitmap(holder.bitmap);

        return convertView;

    }

    static class CategoryHolder {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        BitmapFactory.Options options;
        TextView title;
        ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return categoryList.get(position).getCategoryId();
    }

    @Override
    public Category getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return categoryList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return categoryList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(Category item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return categoryList.indexOf(item);
    }

}
```

Comment: load you bitmaps in the background. google "lazy image loading"

Comment: @SherifelKhatib "lazy image loading" is not getting me anywhere can you if possible describe me more precisely..sorry

Comment: check all the answers in this (I would advice you to use Nostra's Universal Image Loader" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: ya but I already have images in my FileStorage so I would appreciate workaround rather then creating UI Thread...I saw GreenDroid's one but it just downloads Images

Comment: [`String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card`](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: @zapl I tried using universal Image Loader but it quite did not work well, Application class is misbehaving I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably caching your images

Check this out:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: I checked using Lrucache but it gives OutOfMemory due to exceeding application ram

Comment: you can also enlarge the heapsize by setting it to LARGE in the manifestfile.